# Getting bad image quality with android CameraX library

Tags: android, android-camera, jpeg, android-camerax

I am developing a camera application with CameraX library, but I found quality discrepancy native camera app photo and my application photo. I have tested photos taken same lighting condition.
Is there any way to improve image quality with CameraX?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job, but the difference is very hard to notice in some devices->

```
val imageCapture: ImageCapture = remember {
ImageCapture.Builder().setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MAXIMIZE_QUALITY)
    .setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3)
    .setTargetRotation(ROTATION_0).build()}


val cameraProvider = context.getCameraProvider()
cameraProvider.unbindAll()
cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
        lifecycleOwner,
        cameraSelector,
        preview,
        imageCapture
    )
```